# Allowing parent div to resize when child element is getting bigger

Tags: html, css, position

I have a div containing a table , which are centered:

```
<div class="parent">
 <table class="child">
 </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
 position: absolute;
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 5px ;
-moz-border-radius: 5px ;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px ;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

In case the table its getting bigger than div's size it overlapps it,and i need it to resize parent div too.I believe the absolute position is the problem...is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why did you use position: absolute in the first place? Try position: relative;

Comment: try min-width instead and transform:translate instead negative margins, Actually, there is not enough of your code to efficiently help you here

Comment: @JonasGrumann , because the code above works only with absolute position

Comment: @Gcyrillus , that's all of my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use translate and min-width, remove height with absolute :

```css
.parent{
 position: absolute;
 min-width:300px;/* optionnal*/
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 5px ;
 text-align:center;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
.child {
  margin:0 auto;
}
td {
  border:solid;
}
table:hover td{
  padding:2em;/* demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <table class="child">
   <tr>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

or use the flex model

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;/* vertical*/
  justify-content:center;/* horizontal*/
  margin:0;
  }
.parent{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px ;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px ;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.child {

}
td {
  border:solid;
}
table:hover td{
  padding:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <table class="child">
   <tr>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
     <td>td</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```